# Eclipse : Is it possible to generate the setters and getters as *private*?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse : Is it possible to generate the setters and getters as *private* or *protected* instead of *public* (which is the default)?

I'd prefere to manually change the setters/setters I want to be public rather than all of them being public by default!

Update : note that I'm not talking about using the "Source/Generate Getters and Setters..." menu. What I do is type "get" then press "Ctrl-Space" and choose the getXXX() choice (same thing for setters when I need them).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

User the "Access Modifiers" to select which one you want. If you want a different combination, you will have to open this dialog more than once, select the different field for each specific modifier type

[image]

Easiest way to get to this dialog is to right click on the source code and select [Source] -> [Generate Getters and Setters]

Comment: Yes, I know this dialog, but it is not what I use. I'll update my question, sorry it wasn't clear enough.